# Is this a valid JSON object?

Tags: json, jsonp

Is this a valid JSON-object?

```
   serverStatus("amerika": 
   [{
    "server": "1",
    "ah_gold": "1",
    "ah_hardcore": "1",
    "ah_usd": "0",
    "ah_aud": "0",
    "ah_mxn": "0",
    "ah_brl": "0",
    "ah_clp": "0",
    "ah_ars": "0"
   }], "asien": 
   [{
    "server": "1",
    "ah_gold": "1",
    "ah_hardcore": "1"
   }], "europa": 
   [{
    "server": "1",
    "ah_gold": "1",
    "ah_hardcore": "1",
    "ah_eur": "0",
    "ah_gbp": "0",
    "ah_rub": "0"
   }])
```

JSONP-request is done successfully, but in javascript

```
var server = data.asien[0].server;
```

fails..
Any solutions for this?

Comment: It is not a valid JSON object. How are you generating it?

Comment: oh, i forgot to say, that "serverStatus" is the jsonp-callback, therefore i should have asked if it's a valid jsonp-object.. i generated it with php

Comment: It's not a valid JSON data. Use this site to check the give JSON data is valid or not. http://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/

Comment: I realize `serverStatus` is the callback. Its parameter is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You lack a `{` at the beginning, and `}` at the end :

```
serverStatus({"amerika":[{"server":"1","ah_gold":"1","ah_hardcore":"1","ah_usd":"0","ah_aud":"0","ah_mxn":"0","ah_brl":"0","ah_clp":"0","ah_ars":"0"}],"asien":[{"server":"1","ah_gold":"1","ah_hardcore":"1"}],"europa":[{"server":"1","ah_gold":"1","ah_hardcore":"1","ah_eur":"0","ah_gbp":"0","ah_rub":"0"}]})
```

And if you're interested in numbers, don't put them between quotes, that's useless.

The simplest to test your object is to open the chrome developer tools and type

```
console.log(... you object here ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

No it is not a valid JSON Object:

you may check here: http://jsonlint.com/

```
Parse error on line 1: 
    "amerika":[{"server"
    ^
    Expecting '{', '['
```